# After dragging Sortable item A on Droppable with 'over' event revealing sortable items, those items canot be sorted before droping A

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQuery-ui api Sortable and Droppable widgets.
Problem: 
Revealed item in sortable list isn't sortable directly after 'over' event, that caused its revealing. It needs to drop helpler and drag it again to allow sorting revealed content.

Wanted answers:

Primary question: How to allow sorting after 1st 'over' event while still dragging sortable item?

Secondary question: How to reveal hidden content on mouse scroll (over sortable list) or (while dragging sortable item, with same conditions as for primary question)?

HTML:

```html
<div class='tmp'>Sortable List
    <ul class="sortableList">
        <li class="hide" style="display: list-item;">Hide</li>
        <li name='A' class="item ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="test droppableArea">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.hide {display: none !important}
.item {display: list-item !important}
```

jquery-ui:

```
    $(".sortableList").sortable({
    });

    $('.droppableArea').droppable({
        accept: 'li',
        over: function(event, ui) {
              $(this).siblings('.tmp').find('.hide').addClass('item');
        }
    });
```

Full code on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4y93w2m0/12/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question self-answered again, i probably searched with wrong keywords and found answer, after starting studying another topic.

Correct answer is refreshing sortable after showing items:

```
$('.droppableArea').droppable({
        accept: 'li',
        over: function(event, ui) {
              $(this).siblings('.tmp').find('.hide').addClass('item');
              $(".sortableList").sortable('refresh'); // <-- ANSWER
        }
    });
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/s53bvkye/